# How to display the file content of fstream to the console using a function?

Tags: c++

My homework is like this:

> Read `firstName`, `lastName`, `actBalance` from the keyboard and form a record. Add this record to the end of this file if the last name
> and first name are not the same as any existing one in the file (using `createRecord` function). Otherwise update the time and record balance.

My idea is that I will write all the records that I have `cin`'ed by using the `createRecord()` function to the `clientFile` record, and then check for the sameness and write to `copyFile` file later.  But I can not display the `copyFile` content using the `displayFile()` function (this function is given to me and I can not modify it).

Can someone help me solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void
createRecord (fstream & copyFile, fstream & inClientFile, string & firstName,
          string & lastName, double &actBalance)
{
    string recordFirst, recordLast;
    double recordBalance;
    time_t recordTime;
    time_t currentTime = time(0);

    inClientFile.clear ();
    inClientFile.seekg (0);

    while (inClientFile >> recordFirst >> recordLast >> recordBalance >> recordTime)
    {
        inClientFile.seekp(0, ios::end);
        inClientFile << setw (30) << firstName << ' ' << setw (30) << lastName << ' ' << setw (30) << actBalance << ' ' << setw (30) << currentTime;
    }
}

void
updateRecord (fstream & copyFile,fstream& inClientFile,string& firstName,string& lastName, double &actBalance,
          string firstNameArr[], string lastNameArr[])
{
    string recordFirst, recordLast;
    double recordBalance;
    time_t recordTime;
    time_t currentTime = time (0);
    int counter = 0;
    int j = 0;

    inClientFile.clear ();
    inClientFile.seekg (0);

    while (inClientFile >> recordFirst >> recordLast >> recordBalance >> recordTime)
    {
        if(firstNameArr[j] == recordFirst && lastNameArr[j] == recordLast )
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter = 1)
    {
        copyFile.clear ();
        copyFile.seekp(0, ios::end);
        copyFile << firstNameArr[j] << " " << lastNameArr[j] << " " << recordBalance << " " << currentTime << " " << endl;
        j++;
    }
    else if(counter = 2)
    {
        copyFile.clear ();
        copyFile.seekp(0, ios::end);
        copyFile << firstNameArr[j] << " " << lastNameArr[j] << " " << recordBalance << " " << currentTime << " " << endl;
        j++;
    }
}

void
displayFile (fstream & fptr)
{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    double balance;
    int numAct = 0;
    time_t transTime;
    fptr.clear ();
    fptr.seekg (0);

    while (fptr >> str1 >> str2 >> balance >> transTime)
    {
        cout << setw (15) << str1 << setw (15) << str2 << setw (7) << balance << " " << ctime (&transTime);
        numAct++;
    }
    cout << "Number of records in the file:" << numAct << endl;
}

int
main ()
{
    fstream inClientFile ("clientFile.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    fstream copyFile ("copyFile.txt", ios::out);

    if (!inClientFile)
    {
        cout << "Creating a new file: ";
        exit (1);
    }

    cout << "Existing file content:";

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double actBalance;
    string firstNameArr[100];
    string lastNameArr[100];
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Enter first name, last name, and balance: ";
    while (cin >> firstName >> lastName >> actBalance)
    {
        createRecord (copyFile, inClientFile, firstName, lastName, actBalance);
        firstNameArr[i] = firstName;
        lastNameArr[i] = lastName;
        updateRecord(copyFile, inClientFile, firstName, lastName, actBalance, firstNameArr, lastNameArr);
        i++;
    }

    inClientFile.close();
    copyFile.close();

    displayFile (copyFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply store the items in a container, adjust the items how you see fit in the container, write it back to a new file, delete the old file, rename new file with the old file name?  Also, `while (cin >> firstName >> lastName >> actBalance)` -- what if there are more than 100 items in the file?

Comment: `displayFile` looks like it expects the file to be *open* for *reading*.

Comment: `if(counter = 1)` ... `if(counter = 2)` - these are invoking **assignment** not **comparison**.  You need to use `==` instead  of `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not display the `copyFile` content using the `displayFile()` function

That is because you are opening `copyFile` with only `ios::out` access, which means you are opening it for writing only. But `displayFile()` is trying to read from it, which will fail.

You need to either:

- open `copyFile` with `ios::in|ios::out|ios::trunc` access, and then call `copyFile.seekg(0)` to go back to the beginning of the file after you are done writing to it, and before you try to read from it.
- otherwise, close `copyFile` when you are done writing to it, and then re-open it with `ios::in` access before trying to read from it.